# We require a blog plugin to our asp.net website?

Tags: blog, asp.net, iis

We require a blog plugin to our existing ASP.net website. I've used Wordpress before, however as our site is ASP / IIS Wordpress is out (I understand there may be workarounds but would prefer something that works out of the box). We need blog functionality to add in to our existing website template (header, columns etc) so only require a subset of full blog software functionality, as most blog software out there is aimed at creating a whole blog website, whereas we only want it to be a page on our website, in line with the current formatting of the website. What software would you suggest I use?

Comment: WordPress can be catered to fit the style of your existing site and make them co-exist and the visitor never know that 2 engines are used..